# Using Google Maps API to estimate traffic

Tags: google-maps, google-apps-script

I'm trying to call the Google Maps API to get the travel time between two points (***including*** traffic). Here's what I've got so far:

```
function test(){
  //Info: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro

  var baseUrl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?";
  var origin = "Redmond+WA";
  var destination = "Salem+OR";
  var departureTime = "now";
  var trafficModel = "pessimistic";
  var url = baseUrl + "origin=" + origin + "&destination=" + destination + "&departure_time=" + departureTime + "&traffic_model=" + trafficModel;
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  Logger.log("Google Maps API: " + JSON.parse(response).routes[0].legs[0].duration.text);
  Logger.log("Full response from API: \n" + response);
}
```

Unfortunately, I always get a result of `3 hours 43 mins`, no matter when I run the code (and despite the fact that I have defined `departure_time` and `traffic_model`. Any suggestions?

(On a side note, the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro) says that I need to pass in an API key as a required parameter. Obviously - per my code above - I haven't done this yet. But it didn't prevent me from getting a response. Could this be preventing me from using the `traffic_model` parameters?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What field do you see: duration or duration_in_traffic?

According to the documentation

> **duration_in_traffic** indicates the total duration of this leg. This value is an estimate of the time in traffic based on current and historical traffic conditions. See the traffic_model request parameter for the options you can use to request that the returned value is optimistic, pessimistic, or a best-guess estimate. The duration in traffic is returned only if all of the following are true:
>
> - **The request includes a valid API key, or a valid Google Maps APIs Premium Plan client ID and signature.**
> - The request does not include stopover waypoints. If the request includes waypoints, they must be prefixed with via: to avoid stopovers.
> - The request is specifically for driving directions—the mode parameter is set to driving.
> - The request includes a departure_time parameter.
> - Traffic conditions are available for the requested route.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#DirectionsResponseElements

I understand you cannot see duration_in_traffic field, because you don't apply an API key.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Perfect! `duration_in_traffic` was what I was looking for (didn't realize there was a different result than `duration`) Thanks!